# How do I access the responses/response ID's in this JSON string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am using parseJSON to parse this JSON string:

```
json = [
  {
    "Answers": [
      {
        "Responses": [

        ],
        "AnswerID": 1,
        "AnswerText": "Green"
      },
      {
        "Responses": [
          {
            "ResponseID": 1,
            "RespondingUser": null,
            "ResponseDate": "\/Date(1351694241577)\/"
          },
          {
            "ResponseID": 2,
            "RespondingUser": null,
            "ResponseDate": "\/Date(1351694245093)\/"
          }
        ],
        "AnswerID": 2,
        "AnswerText": "Blue"
      }
    ],
    "QuestionID": 1,
    "QuestionText": "Favourite colour?",
    "ClosingDate": "\/Date(1351953058527)\/",
    "AskingUser": null
  }
]

var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

but how do I get the responses/response ID's out of 'result' now? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is not a JSON string, it is a Javascript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ ] = array

{ } = object

You have an array, lose the wrapping square brackets.

alert(json.Answers[0].AnswerText) = "Green"

Comment: If "responses" are supposed to all be a children of "answers" then there's something wrong with your JSON structure.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! - What is wrong with responses? I guess this could be a more serious problem?

Comment: The first "responses", child of "answers" is empty, then later you declare another "responses" outside of this structure.

Comment: Did you run the JSON through jsonlint to verify it?

Comment: The structure is valid, but is not self-consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the for-in loop:

```
 for (i in result[0].Answers)
 {
    // do something with result[0].Answers[i].Responses
 }
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Why the "not useful" vote? did I do something wrong?

Comment: result is still alerts as null :/

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var a in result[0].Answers) {
    result[0].Answers[a].AnswerID // Do something with it.
}
```

Comment: I actually think 'a' would be an index within the result[0].Answers[] array.  You would reference it like this: 'result[0].Answers[a]'